# Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 default email attachment location

Tags: email, external-sd, attachments, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

How can I change the default location on my Samsung Galaxy tab 4 for email attachments? When I download, say, a picture attachment it automatically sends it to internal device storage. I want to send my downloaded email attachments to my microSD card.

Comment: Which email client are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Well the tab4 runs on android kitkat. Google has added restrictions to apps on editing data on sd card. Only the default file manager has permission to edit sdcard. So you cannot send attachments directly to sdcard. You have to move them using default file manager.